# How to convert a picture before sending to the server?

Tags: android

in my current app I am sending pictures to my server. Now I have the problem that these pictures are sometimes too big. What is the best approach to downsize a picture before sending it to the server. Currently I stored the URI of the picture in a database (/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/SF.png) and send it to the server. I want to shrink the resolution of the image so that it will need a smaller amount of diskpace. Is there a way to convert images in android?

Can someone help me how to solve this in a good way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i used the following code to send the image to server, here i convert the image to byte array. Here first you need to decode the image from URI then convert the bitmap to byte array.

**To decode bitmap from URI:**

```
Bitmap imageToSend= decodeBitmap("Your URI");
```

**Method to decode the URI**

```
Bitmap getPreview(URI uri) {
    File image = new File(uri);
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1))
        return null;
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);     
}
```

**Code to send the image to server**

```
try {


            ByteArrayOutputStream bosRight = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageToSend.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bosRight);
            byte[] dataRight = bosRight.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("url to send");
            ByteArrayBody babRight = new ByteArrayBody(dataRight,
                    "ImageName.jpg");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("params", babRight);
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
                Log.v("Response value is", sResponse);
                JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                String successTag = postObj.getString("success");
                if (successTag.equals("1")) {
                    imageDeletion();
                } else {

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: thanks, can you show the compress method of your imageToSend Object

Comment: imageToSend would the object of your Bitmap which you want to send to server.

Comment: @SulabhGupta: No it's a decoded bitmap, please see the updated code. I mentioned the sample name, you may change as per yours

Answer (score 0):

for sending the image to a server you can encode it in `Base64` and then send the Base64 encoded string to the server...
the base64 class in android doesn't support encoding so you will have to download the Bae64 java class file... You get it here http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ 
after that its very simple.For example

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),

R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

String encodedstring=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

Then send the encoded string as a normal name value pair

and a good example is given in this link http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/